# Create a Grand Central Dispatch queue that will only be on one thread, for Core Data

Tags: multithreading, core-data, grand-central-dispatch

Is there a way to create GCD queue that runs on just one thread?
I want to use that queue to handle Core Data operations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes; just create the queue with the flag `DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL` (this is also the default). But do be careful moving core data operations onto another thread. A given `NSManagedObjectContext` must only be used on a single thread, so you'll need two contexts, one for your main thread and one for your background thread. Doing this correctly can require some care.

You may want to investigate `UIManagedDocument` (if this is iOS5), which does much of this work for you. At the very least you should read over its documentation so you learn about its use of parent and child contexts for multithreading.

Comment: This answer seems to be out of date. From the docs: "Serial queues (also known as private dispatch queues) execute one task at a time in the order in which they are added to the queue. The currently executing task runs on a distinct thread (**which can vary from task to task**) that is managed by the dispatch queue"

Answer (score 0):

When a Managed Object Context is created, you specify its concurrency type.  If you specify NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType or NSMainQueueConcurrencyType, then the MOC will already take care of running on its own thread.  Specifically...

```
NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
// Do other MOC initializations stuff...
[moc.performBlock:^{
    // All code in this block will run in the proper thread for the Managed Object Context.
}];
```

FWIW, NSMainQueueConcurrencyType works the same way, but it is attached to the main queue.  You can not call performBlock on a MOC created with NSConfinementConcurrencyType, the creation and all work must happen in the same thread.  In that case only, would you need to create your own queue.